# I am trying to create a password checker in java with a length of 8 characters or more, one upper case, one lower case, and a symbol.

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, nested

I am really new to all this so let me use that as a preface in case this looks really really bad. The details are in the title but it is basically equal to or 8 characters in length, one upper case, one lower case, and a symbol that is neither a letter or number

```
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); 
       String outputString = "";
       String lowerCaseAlphabet = ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z");
       String upperCaseAlphabet = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");
       String numbers.equals ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0");
       String symbols = ("!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(",  ")", "-", "=", "+", "\", ", "{", "[", ";", ":", "/", "?", ">", ".", "<", ","); 


       System.out.print("Please enter a password: ");
       outputString = s.nextLine();

       System.out.println("Entered Password:\t" + outputString);
       if (outputString.length() > 8)
         if (outputString.contains(upperCaseAlphabet)) 
            if (outputString.contains(lowerCaseAlphabet))
               if (outputString.contains(numbers))
                  if (outputString.contains(symbols))
         System.out.println("Verdict:\t\t Valid"); 
       else {
       System.out.println("Vredict:\t\t Invalid");
       }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to learn **Regex** expressions, its notable more easy. Check the link, its a online web to create Regex Expressions! [RegExr](http://regexr.com)

Comment: And you need to learn about basic java syntax rules. The code you posted doesn't even compile - your String declarations are plain wrong. Plus: there is no point in putting so many tags on your question!

Comment: @Bene Just have a look at his code. It doesn't even compile. This code is full of problems.

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

You are clearly a beginner, so suggesting you a Regex solution is out of the question. You need to check if user password contains any big character, so you need to iterate through whole password and check if any of the letters is in array of big letters, something like this:

```java
public boolean checkIfPasswordHasBigLetter(String password){
  List<Character> list = Arrays.asList(upperCaseAlphabet);
  for(char character : password.toCharArray()){
    if(list.contains(character))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Same with the symbols and lower letters etc., extract each separate functionality to a new method. Then check everything like this:

```java
String password = scanner.nextLine();
if(hasBigLetter(password) && hasLowLetter(password) && hasEightLetters(password) && hasSymbol(password))
  System.out.println("Password is fine");
else
  System.out.println("Password is invalid");
```

Ofcourse this code is nowhere near perfect, but I'm not gonna write everything for you, plus this problem can be solved in much simpler way, but like I said, you are a beginner so such solution is gonna help you more. You should learn about Java syntax and use Eclipse or some other IDE, it's gonna help you a lot with syntax problems.

btw. your alphabets should be arrays of char, not String, since a letter is only one character, not a string of characters.